# Can't part siblings in a tikz tree picture

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-external

I'm having some trouble parting siblings in a tree drawn by tikz. I'm making a parsing tree for an assignment. I have already made the tree, but there is some overlapping. I tried to use  the

```
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=2.3cm}
```

style, and it have worked great for parts of the tree, but when I use it on the fifth level, (where the problem is) other parts of the tree, also on level 5, gets messed up!. I then tried to use the command

```
    child{[sibling distance = 3cm]node{$ElementBody$}
```

method, for that specific node, but there is no difference in the tree, when compiling the code, and i have no idea why!

Here is my code:

```
\[ 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=12mm,
sibling distance = 12mm,
level 3/.style={sibling distance=8cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=2.3cm} 
]
\node {$XMLFile$}
  child {node {$TaggedElement$}
    child{node {$StartTag$}
  }
  child{node {$ElementBody$}
        child{node{$ElementBody$}
          child{node{$Element$}
            child{node{$TaggedElement$}
                child{node{$StartTag$}
                }
                child{node{$Element$}
                }
                child{node{$EndTag$}
                }
            }
          }              
        }
        child{[sibling distance = 3cm]node{$ElementBody1!$}
            child{node{$ElementBody$}
                child{node{$Element$}
                    child{node{$TaggedElement$}
                        child{node{$StartTag$}
                        }
                        child{node{$Element$}
                        }
                        child{node{$EndTag$}
                        }
                    }
                }              
            }
            child{node{$ElementBody$}
                child{node{$Element$}
                    child{node{$TaggedElement$}
                        child{node{$StartTag$}
                        }
                        child{node{$Element$}
                        }
                        child{node{$EndTag$}
                        }
                    }
                }              
            }
          }
      }
      child{node {$EndTag$}
      }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit, I cannot get this to work with `sibling distance`. In the following, I'm using an alternative solution. I introduce two missing nodes between the clashing sibling nodes.

One minor comment, writing `$TaggedElement$` doesn't look nice because LaTeX will typeset the letters in `TaggedElement` as a product. Using `$\mathit{TaggedElement}$` looks much nicer.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=12mm,
sibling distance = 12mm,
level 3/.style={sibling distance=8cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=2.3cm} 
]
\node {$XMLFile$}
  child {node {$TaggedElement$}
    child{node {$StartTag$}
  }
  child{node {$ElementBody$}
        child{node{$ElementBody$}
          child{node{$Element$}
            child{node{$TaggedElement$}
                child{node{$StartTag$}}
                child{node{$Element$}}
                child{node{$EndTag$}}
            }
          }              
        }
        child{node{$ElementBody1!$}
            child{node{$ElementBody$}
                child{node{$Element$}
                    child{node{$TaggedElement$}
                        child{node{$StartTag$}}
                        child{node{$Element$}}
                        child{node{$EndTag$}}
                    }
                }              
            }
            child[missing]
            child[missing]
            child{node{$ElementBody$}
                child{node{$Element$}
                    child{node{$TaggedElement$}
                        child{node{$StartTag$}}
                        child{node{$Element$}}
                        child{node{$EndTag$}}
                    }
                }
            }
          }
      }
      child{node {$EndTag$}}
};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works great, although it's kinda a workaround! Nevertheless, it fixes the problem. Thanks alot! Really appreciated! :)